# ChannelObject::connfail Error

Tags: bugs, dynamic

My Mathematica keeps deadlock in DynamicEvaluation and throws the following error upon Abort. How to stop this behavior?

```
During evaluation of In[1]:=
  ChannelObject::connfail: Could not connect to the server "mqtts://channelbroker-mqtt.wolframcloud.com:8883/".
```

- Operating system: macOS 14.1.2 (23B92)
- Mathematica version: 13.2.1.0